# Github not understood project start

Tags: python, github

I'm interested in a project on Github and I'm trying to run it locally, kindly note that I'm new to git. The Github README provides the following getting started commands:

```
Getting started
cd into this directory after cloning the repo
start the app
$ python app.py /images/directory
```

what does `/images/directory` mean? There is no `/images` directory in the cloned project.

Comment: The question is quite unclear. What is app.py doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you do to get up and running from a git project:

1. locate the git URL (ends with .git usually)
2. Clone or download it
3. install requirements, for python this would be:

   pip install -r requirements.txt
4. run the app with given parameters

Now step 4 is presumably where you run into trouble,  the app seems to require 1 parameter (the image directory). This image directory is a folder on your computer.

So point to a directory on your machine. For example:

```
python app.py /home/mastermindzh/Pictures
```

**Edit**
After looking at the git repo my suspicions are confirmed.

Comment: yes your answer was helpful shouldn't have he wrote /images_directory instead as the way he wrote is confusing.

Comment: He/she probably should have, yes. The documentation is a bit lacking but overall it seems to be allright.

You could dive further into git and make a pull-request on it :) 
Or simply go to "issues" and tell him/her about your confusion and possibly link to this SO question.

If my answer helped you further please mark it as accepted so others won't have to waste their time posting a similar answer :)

Glad to be of service, enjoy!

Comment: And another question, does it seem to have an option where i can already give a file of coordinates and add to them cause i can't see any parameter to do so.

Comment: Unfortunately not. it only gives you the ability to insert 2 parameters (a directory and an output directory). You'll have to use the REST endpoint /add to add a label (or modify the project and call add yourself)